# How does the SuperNet NXT Multigateway Exchange work?

Tags: nxt, multigateway

I'm still trying to figure out how the multigateway exchange works for nxt. i see you can put your bitcoins and other altcoins into the system and trade on top of the asset exchange using the nxt wallet creating a decentralized exchange. my concerns are:

- Do my bitcoins / altcoins goto a centralized wallet like how typical exchanges work today?
- Who controls the coin wallets and what if they need to be rebooted?
- What prevents the multigateway admins from running away with our coins?
- What are some major advantages to over typical exchanges today like cryptsy / poloniex / bter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantage of the MGW exchange over traditional exchanges is that for protocols which support multisig, all funds are stored under 2/3 multisig accounts on 3 geographically separate servers, most likely, owned by different entities.